# If Gerar part of Eretz Israel, why it is referred by Rashi as "hard land' (Breshit, 26;12)?

Tags: parashat-toldot

If Gerar part of Eretz Israel, why it is referred  by Rashi as "hard land'  (Breshit, 26;12)?

Comment: It is not part of Eretz Yisroel? See the first Rashi there

Comment: See the gur aryeh and the Mizrahi that seem to give it some sort of middle status. Can’t be that it’s chutz laaretz because Yitzchak was not allowed to leave Israel, but it was not still considered the ‘main’ part of EY.